# When do you need to pass an exception object to Logger.exception

Tags: python, exception, logging

When do you need to pass an exception object to `Logger.exception`?

For me the following pattern is better, as I can write a custom message:

```
try:
    my_function()
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception('custom message')
```

Is there a reason to do this:

```
try:
    my_function()
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e)  # the difference is passing the exception object to the log
```

Which information am I losing by not passing it?

Comment: doesn't `logger.exception` already contains all the information? @Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the specific that you are showing here there is no loss of information. The logging module uses `sys.exc_info()` to obtain information about the current exception so as long as you are inside that exception block there is no need to pass in the exception. It is only needed for scenarios where the exception object isn't the current exception in a scenario like this for example:

```
import logging

try:
    some_func()
except ValueError as e:
    # handle ValueError here
    err = e
except OtherException as e:
    # handle OtherException here
    err = e
except Exception as e:
    # handle Exception here
    err = e

if err:
    logging.exception(err) # here we need to pass the exception object expicitely
```

It may be worth noting that you can also do both, pass in an exception and have a message by using `logging.exception("your message", exc_info=e)`.

`logging.exception` is just a convenience wrapper around `logging.error` and is actually very simply implemented like this: (in cpython)

```
    def exception(self, msg, *args, exc_info=True, **kwargs):
        self.log(ERROR, msg, *args, exc_info=exc_info, **kwargs)
```